# Using UIDocumentPickerViewController to import folder on network drive

Tags: ios, swift, samba

I am trying to import the contents of a folder in iOS.  When I try to list the files either locally on the device or in iCloud it works fine, but when I try to list the files that live on a network drive it doesn't work.  I am using Apple's example code, but I'm not having any luck.

I created a seperate app to make sure it wasn't something else I might have introduced.

In this example, no files would be printed/enumerated.

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

@main
struct OpenNetworkFileApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var documentPickerIsPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            documentPickerIsPresented = true
        }, label: {
            Text("Click Me")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $documentPickerIsPresented) {
            DocumentPicker()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

public struct DocumentPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    public func makeCoordinator() -> DocumentPickerCoordinator {
        return DocumentPickerCoordinator()
    }
    
    public func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) -> some UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let contentTypes: [UTType] = [.folder]
        
        let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: contentTypes, asCopy: false)
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>) { }
}

public class DocumentPickerCoordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        let shouldStopAccessing = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        defer {
            if shouldStopAccessing {
                url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            }
        }
        var coordinatedError: NSError?
        NSFileCoordinator().coordinate(readingItemAt: url, error: &coordinatedError) { (folderURL) in
            let keys: [URLResourceKey] = [.nameKey, .isDirectoryKey]
            let fileList = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: folderURL.resolvingSymlinksInPath(), includingPropertiesForKeys: keys)!
            for case let file as URL in fileList {
                guard folderURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
                    fatalError("Handle the failure here.")
                }
                defer { folderURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }

                print(file)
            }
        }
    }

    public func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens? (I can guess but I need to hear it from you.)

Comment: Whoops, added more information.